# is it possible to jit a function which uses jax.numpy.unique?

Tags: jit, jax

The following code does not work:

```
def get_unique(arr):
    return jnp.unique(arr)

get_unique = jit(get_unique)
get_unique(jnp.ones((10,)))
```

The error message compains about the use of `jnp.unique`:

```
FilteredStackTrace: jax._src.errors.ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: Traced<ShapedArray(float32[10])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=0/1)>
The error arose in jnp.unique()
```

The [documentation on sharp bits](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#python-control-flow-jit) explains that jit doesn't work if the shape of internal arrays depends on argument values. This is exactly the case here.

According to the docs, a potential workaround is to specify static parameters. But this doesn't apply to my case. The parameters will change for almost every function call. I have split up my code into a preprocessing step, which performs calculations such as this `jnp.unique`, and a computation step which can be jitted.

But still I'd like to ask, is there some workaround that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the reasons you mention, there's currently no way to use `jnp.unique` on a non-static value.

In similar cases, JAX sometimes adds extra parameters that can be used to specify a static size for the output (for example, the `size` parameter in [`jax.numpy.nonzero`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.nonzero.html)) but nothing like that is currently implemented for `jnp.unique`. If that is something you'd like, it would be worth filing a [feature request](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=Feature_request.md).